# How to restrict the visible size of select box in Grails to 1?

Tags: grails, select

With the `<g:select>` tag... sometimes it displays normally like a selection drop down box, while sometimes it displays with multiple rows, this is very annoying.... Even I put the size="1" into the `<g:select>`, it still displays multiple rows... is there anyone knows how to make `<g:select>` display correctly? with only one item visible, like a dropdown box. Thanks!!

```
<g:select size="1" id="s_caseID" name="s_caseID" value="${t1T2InstanceListTotal?.Accession_No}"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"
          from='${t1T2InstanceListTotal}'
          optionKey="Accession_No" optionValue="Accession_No" onclick="this.form.submit();" >
</g:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [taglib code](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy) that cause the `multiple="multiple"` attribute to be rendered (if not explicitly declared on the tag):

```
    def value = attrs.remove('value')
    if (value instanceof Collection && attrs.multiple == null) {
        attrs.multiple = 'multiple'
    }
```

Therefore, it looks like you're passing a `Collection` as the `<g:select>`'s `value` attribute instead of a single value. Is that what you're intending to do?

Comment: I just want to simply display a select dropdown box (1 row), but it turns out that a dropdown box with multiple rows display is presented even if i set size="1" and multiple="false". This is driving me crazy...

Comment: @Kevin - Have you verified the type of what you're passing in for the `value` attribute? I'm almost certain it's a list of values instead of a single value.

Comment: I just attached the code of my select box in above. Would you mind to take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin - If you print out the value of `${t1T2InstanceListTotal?.Accession_No}`, what do you get? Just print it out from your GSP file right before the select list: `${"VAL=" + t1T2InstanceListTotal?.Accession_No}`.

Comment: @Kevin - Looking at your other question, I'm guessing it's going to print `[83]`. This means `Accession_No` is a List with a single element (83). You need to figure out why `Accession_No` is a list and not a single value like you expect it to be. Since it *is* a list, **my answer for this question still describes what is happening**: passing a list as the `value` to a `<g:select/>` will cause it to render with a size > 1.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `multiple` attribute to `false`

```
<g:select name="cars"
      from="${Car.list()}"
      value="${person?.cars*.id}"
      optionKey="id" 
      multiple="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "value" is a list, **g:select** always considers it as a multiple select. To avoid this and have a single select drop-down just ignore the **value** attribute and use **keys** option instead!

This works fine for me!

```
`<g:select id="s_caseID" name="s_caseID" from='${t1T2InstanceListTotal}' 
      noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"          
      keys="${t1T2InstanceListTotal?.Accession_No}" onclick="this.form.submit();">
 </g:select>`
```